# How to use gtalk on fedora linux?

Tags: fedora, software-installation

I use gmail account for chat, but i want gtalk standalone application just like in windows.  can i install standalone gtalk client on linux ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. But any Jabber/XMPP client should work with the GTalk service.

Comment: Take a look [here](https://admin.fedoraproject.org/pkgdb/apps/search/xmpp?_csrf_token=cadf675b9486695aff241d3e87ede90ef8335c24) for some available packages.